# POST params stripped .htaccess basic auth

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, post, basic-authentication

I'm basically trying to send an AJAX-Add-to-Cart-POST-Request by WooCommerce WordPress Plugin. The Plugin does so by sending form-data to a URL that already contains a GET param:

```
jQuery.post('/?wc-ajax=add_to_cart', { product_id: '123', quantity: 1 }, function(response) {...});
```

This works fine locally, but on the staging server, which is secured by basic htaccess auth:

```
AuthName "Staging"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

the POST params are completely stripped from the request, means when I remove the above or "whitelist" my IP like so:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from 1.2.3.4
Satisfy Any
```

everything works fine.

Is there something I'm missing? I could not find any documentation why this behaves the way it does.

The site runs on an apache 2.4 server with php 7.1.17, OS is Debian 8.10.